# Should the expression x && (~x) return 1 or 0? And does it depend on the compiler?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, conditional-operator

In C, given "short x = 0xFFF0" what is the output of "x && (~x)".
This question was proposed to me on a quiz and the answer for it was 0. Although when compiled 1(true) is returned. Why is that?

```
int main()
{
    short x = 0xFFF0;
    printf("%X\n", x && (~x));
    return 0;
}
```

What I know is that "x = 0xFFF0" and "~x = 0x000F".
when we do "logical and" its 1 && 1 which returns 1(true). However, the professor thinks otherwise by stating that the "bitwise and" should be done first 0xFFF0 & 0x000F = 0x0000 which is 0 (false). Is this a problem with an outdated compiler or something unexplainable?

Comment: It should return 1. Did you mean `x & (~x)`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, nope. I'm talking about x && (~x).

Comment: Ok, then `1`.  `0xFFF0` is truthy and so is `~0xFFF0`

Comment: *the professor thinks otherwise by stating that the "bitwise and" should be done first 0xFFF0 & 0x000F*  There is no "bitwise and" in the posted code.  If your professor feels there is one, you'd be justified in asking for a tuition refund.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I'll forward this forum to him and I hope it changes his mind about this particular case.

Comment: Just send him code that performs the operation.

Comment: Since `x` will be true if it is any value other than 0, and `~x` will be true if it is any number other than `-1` (2's Complement) or `0xFFFF` and the `&&` operator returns true if both operands are true and false otherwise, `x && (~x)` is equivalent to `x != 0 && x != -1` so it will return true if `x` any value other than `0` or `-1` and false otherwise. Since `0xFFF0` is neither `0` nor `-1`, your expression will return `1`/true.

Comment: `short x = 0xFFF0;` initializes `x` with a value outside the `short` range, thus it gets an implementation defined value - could even be 0 with a hostile compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at `x && (~x)` part by part.

- `x` by itself is not zero and will therefore count as `true` in boolean contexts as when using the logical `&&` (AND).
- `~x` by itself is not zero either, so `true`.
- `true && true` is `true`:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    short x = 0xFFF0;
    
    printf("%s\n", x != 0 ? "true" : "false");         // true
    printf("%s\n", ~x != 0 ? "true" : "false");        // true
    printf("%s\n", true && true ? "true" : "false");   // true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C17 §6.5.13 ¶3:

> The `&&` operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type `int`.

`&&` is the logical AND operator. As its name suggests, it performs a logical AND operation.

- `x` is non-zero (a true value), and
- `~x` is non-zero (a true value), so
- `x && (~x)` returns `1` (a true value).

If your professor stated what you said they did, they are mistaken. Could they have been talking about `if ( x & (~x) )`?

Comment: This was the exact question on the quiz. "short X1 = 0xFFF0;" Provide the values in hexadecimal. short Y1 = (X1 && (~X1)) == 0. Answer key has Y1 = 0x1, but most of you believe that Y1 = 0x0. My question above was only concerned with the "X1 && (~X1)" part though (without the ==).

Comment: It's not belief. It's what the spec calls for, and it's easily tested. I suspect they simply overlooked the `== 0` when finding the answer, or maybe it was added later and they forgot to change the answer key. Did you ask them about it?

Comment: Yes, I asked them about it and no they didnt overlook the (==). This was giving me quite the head scratch.

Comment: Well, I can't explain how or why they think that, but it's clearly wrong :)